# How to stop nginx from being automatically started on install?

Tags: nginx, apt

I am trying to install Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 via the following command:
`sudo apt-get install nginx`

But I am getting the following error:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-07-11 16:41:31 UTC; 6ms ago
  Process: 17851 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 31524 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 11 16:41:31 vm systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy s...r...
Jul 11 16:41:31 vm nginx[17851]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: N...ory)
Jul 11 16:41:31 vm nginx[17851]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jul 11 16:41:31 vm systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 11 16:41:31 vm systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse ...ver.
Jul 11 16:41:31 vm systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 11 16:41:31 vm systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) | nginx-full (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) | nginx-extras (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
  Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
```

I think it is trying start nginx automatically by default after installing, but cannot find nginx configuration files. How can I stop it from starting automatically just after install, so that my `apt-get install` command does not fail.

Comment: There is problem with dependencies. Your `nginx` is not started.

Answer (score 4):

In Debian based distributions, the unfortunate default for services on installation is started and enabled. This generally causes the issue of frightful error spew upon the installation of services that contain no end-to-end default configuration of their own, as well as a bunch of garbage output when using CM products that read such an output stream directly, such as Ansible.

You can alter this package default, but it will require that you repackage the application (in this case nginx) on either the machine locally or via something with a mirroring service such as Foreman or Satellite.

I personally solve this by using CentOS wherever I can, which has a reasonable default of "stopped and disabled". That's not a very universal solution, though.

Use following steps to repackage deb package:

1: Extract deb package

```
`# dpkg-deb -x <package.deb> <dir>`
```

2: Extract control information from a package

```
`# dpkg-deb -e <package.deb> <dir/DEBIAN>`
```

3. After any package changes are completed, repack the deb

`# dpkg-deb -b <dir> <new-package.deb>`

4. You can either install this deb locally, or add it to a mirror service (if you have that).

Alternatively, here is a clever method for getting around this issue that I'm shamelessly ripping from [major.io](https://major.io/2014/06/26/install-debian-packages-without-starting-daemons/). It acts like a switch that you can turn on and off to prevent new packages from starting their services. Keep in mind that this does NOT "disable" these services, so a reboot will render them started unless you explicitly set them to disabled beforehand:

If you’d like to prevent daemons from starting after installing a package, just toss a few lines into /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d:

```
cat > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d < < EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo "All runlevel operations denied by policy" >&2
exit 101
EOF
```

Now, install any packages that you need and the daemons will remain stopped until you start them (or reboot the server). Be sure to remove the policy file you added once you’re done installing your packages.

If you're using this with something like Ansible, this will be easy to turn on and off pre and post execution. It will also stop the problem of ugly error spew when installing Debian packages.